# Dividing a square field into 5 equal regions

Tags: geometry, optimization, dissection

A farmer has a 10m x 10m field that has fences around the perimeter. What is the least number of 1m fences he needs to add to divide the field into 5 regions of equal area?

Comment: Can we use fractions of fence? Or must every section have integer length?

Comment: @fljx I am going to say yes as it opens up extra solutions that I didn't consider.

Comment: It doesn't make a better sense to keep both the original problem and the one that replaced it visible, does it? Or maybe post a separate one. A generalization of the original one to arbitrary curved fences is very interesting. Both are indeed very interesting, just very different.

Comment: feel free to post a new question where curved fences are allowed

Comment: That would probably be more appropriate on math stackexchange :/

Comment: “feel free to post”—Thanks for the permission. The thing is, it is the exact _original_ formulation of _your_ puzzle (it didn't explicitly mention straight or curved fences). I cannot promise to post it, tho, too busy. If I do, you'll get a proper attribution, of course.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, in any case, be it fractional/integer, straight/curved, a proof of the solution's optimality is desirable. And Math.SE is a place I wouldn't go to unless I'd crave getting snubbed. Which never happened so far, FWIW. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit/Note: I gave this answer assuming fractional fences where not allowed.
As such I did not carefully think about the second picture.

Obviously that answer is not optimal if fractional fence solutions are allowed!
Considering the talk if that should be another question: I won't give my better solution here. (evil grin).

> Since farmers tend not to care about unit squares, 26 is doable.
>  If the farmer does not mind setting the saw into his fences, the optimal solution is around 25 1/4 fence (probably not worth it for the farmer, and probably not the intent of this question).  But this suggests 25 is not possible.
>  [image]

Comment: Cool second solution! I didn't think of that.

Comment: Can you think of a proof that the solution 2 is optimal (a) considering only straight line fences, and (b) considering any non-intersecting, possibly curved lines? My head explodes... I'st one of the simplest and at the same time one of the most disccombobulating tiling problems I ever seen. Delightful!

Comment: @kkm: see edit. PS: only straight lines does not mean anything if fences of any length are allowed.

Comment: Re: 2nd solution...  I saw this in the 'Hot Network Questions' next to the 'Puzzling' Icon and exclaimed 'The solution is right there!' XD

Answer (score 12):

This is an attempt to locally optimize the [solution by Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/118997/63291).

> Some theory suggests that when you have segments meeting in a problem like this one, they should meet at 120 degree angles.  And then to compensate for the fact that it's not possible to use straight line segments anymore, we use circular arcs instead.  If my calculations are correct, then this achieves 25.0211 units of fence.

> [image: circular arcs and line segments meeting at 120 degrees]

> Some detail if someone wants to check my calculations: if the square has vertices at coordinates (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), and (0,1); then one of the points where three segments meet is (0.5, 0.791588112238442); the center of one of the arcs is (0.10168323124074008, 0.10168323124074008) and the radius of the circular arc is 0.7966335375185202.  The radius squared is exactly one-fifth the reciprocal of 1-sqrt(3)+pi/3.  The circular arcs are each one-twelfth of a full circle (that is, 30 degrees).

But perhaps the optimal solution has a different global structure?

Comment: With my own calculations I also get 25.0211293 for the fence length.  Looks good.  And according to this blog, it is the optimal structure. https://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/pagesmembres/bogosel/anisotropic.html

Comment: Since the arcs are 1/12th of a circle, would 3 of them would fit in this square as a quarter of the circle and intersect at the vertical & horizontal lines?  Or is the origin of this larger circle outside this square?

Comment: @Jim The radius is ~7.966.  You are right that if you extend the arcs you can get 4 1/4 circles that fit nicely in a square.  But the outer square is larger than that.

Comment: By the way, this answer shows that the 26-unit solution must be optimal with unit fences, regardless how you arrange the fences.

Comment: Nice. It's basically a special case of a soap-bubble optimisation/simulation. I happen to write one last summer (screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rpnh5xtm9vhily/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPad%20Pro%20%2812.9-inch%29%20%285th%20generation%29%20-%202022-12-13%20at%2015.03.28.png)

Comment: I find that the 'divide a square in 4 equal parts' solution also uses 120degree angles and (thus) is not 4way symmetrical even more counterintuitive at first sight.

Answer (score 11):

The best I can achieve with orthogonal fences is:

> 26

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

> This answer is good enough if the total length of the new fences is an integer (26): [image]

Why a better integer answer is not possible:

> If it can be 25 or lower, the total fence length is $25*2+40 = 90$ with the average perimeter of a region being $18$. If so, the region's shorter dimension will be $4$ (with the shape being a $4$x$5$ rectangle), but we need different perimeters than $18$ too. Even the shortest distances through the shapes decrease less than they increase to keep the same area, so this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I think a *lateral* answer can be given if farmer thinks out of the box

> or better, use the box.

So the farmer can achieve

> zero meters of **additional** fences.
>  Farmer can reposition the fences that are on the border of the field "box"

case 1) Fractional fences are allowed

> Given that there would be no lower limit on the the fence size, we can have infinitesimal small, shapes. I do not think that this is a very interesting case.

case 2) Fractional fences are not allowed

> The farmer would use at least 1m of fence each time.
>  So the farmer can build 5 squares that shares one or more side each.
>  A good configuration using squares is
>  [image: good 5 square configuration]

> Not sure that is the best general configuration, but the additional fences is still 0, as it requires 15 meters of fences and it can take them from the 40m of the border.

> A better configuration could be achieved using equilateral triangles of 1m side
>  [image: equilateral]
>  so you can use only 11m of fences.
>  Still, I am not sure that is the best configuration.

> Basically this is a try to answer to the question "Minimize the non-fractional 1m fences that the farmer need to create 5 equal area regions". I think other answers that are not exploiting the border fences could be re-adapted to answer the question and achieve even a better minimization!